# Returned json from connecting to mysql via ajax in login has html code in it

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am developing an login option on a website. I make a jquery ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
        //Verificar si hay mensaje de error
        if ($('#loginError').is(':visible')) {
            $('#loginError').addClass('hide');
        }
        $('#ajaxloader').removeClass('hide');
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "includes/appResponses.inc.php",
    data: str + "&accion=login&id=" + Math.random(),
    success: function (response) {
        //Verificar errores
        if (response.respuesta == true) {
            alert(response.mensaje);
            window.location.href = "index.php";
            $('#loginError').addClass('hide');
        } else {
            $('#loginError').removeClass('hide');
        }

        $('#ajaxloader').addClass('hide');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("ERROR GENERAL. " + textStatus + ". " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

when i use a a good login it returns a normal JSON object but when i fail to login it return a error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

because the returned "JSON" is this:

```
 <br /> <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'roots'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\cazares\includes\mainFunctions.inc.php on line <i>37</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>248760</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\cazares\includes\appResponses.inc.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\appResponses.inc.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>265568</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>include( <font color='#00bb00'>'C:\wamp\www\cazares\includes\mainFunctions.inc.php'</font> )</td>
<td title='C:\wamp\www\cazares\includes\appResponses.inc.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\appResponses.inc.php<b>:</b>17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td>
    <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td>
    <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>267256</td>
    <td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/mysqli.mysqli' target='_new'>mysqli</a>
( )</td>
    <td title='C:\wamp\www\cazares\includes\mainFunctions.inc.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\mainFunctions.inc.php<b>:</b>37</td>
</tr>
</table>
</font>{"respuesta":false,"mensaje":"Error al conectar con la base de datos","contenido":""}
```

My connection is made like this:

```
if (defined('server') && defined('user') && defined('pass') && defined('mainDataBase')) {

    $mysqli = new mysqli(server, user, pass, mainDataBase);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        $errorDbConexion = true;
    } else {
        //Evitando problemas con acentos
        $mysqli - > query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it says that your user can't login with the credentials your using... So are you really, really sure that your using the right credentials?

Comment: I will paste the answer i used to another user: 
 
That was on purpose to generate the error, when I use 'root' it return a correct JSON object. The problem appears only when the loggin credentials are incorrect. But is not a JSON object but an html code with the JSON in the bottom. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) enabled and this generates 'pretty' error messages by formatting them for display using HTML.

The error message Xdebug is trying to show you is:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'roots'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\cazares\includes\mainFunctions.inc.php on line 37
```

You should fix this error in your PHP code and then your returned JSON will be valid.

Comment: I am using Twig and it comes with the Xdebug. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to get rid of the warning message. You can do this in multiple ways.

You can use the [@ operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to suppress errors or you can set your [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to a level that it doesn't report any warnings. You could also simply make PHP only log errors and not display errors using `ini_set('display_errors', false');`

Comment: Setting display_errors to false solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that your script is not able to connect to the database. Try verifying username and password which you are sending in connection request.

Also your error shows that the username you are using is 'roots', while default username of MySQL is 'root'. This may be a cause of error.

You just need to resolve the connection error.

Hiding Error is not a good idea.

Comment: That was on purpose to generate the error, when I use 'root' it return a correct JSON object. The problem appears only when the loggin credentials are incorrect. But is not a JSON object but an html code  with the JSON in the bottom. Thank you.